# emmeans - control vs treatment for more than one factor

Tags: r, p-value, emmeans

I'm using [emmeans](/questions/tagged/emmeans) to perform custom comparisons to a control group. The `trt.vs.ctrl` approach works perfectly for me if I'm only interested in comparing one factor, but then fails (or I fail) when I set the comparison to be more complicated (i.e., the control group is described by a specific combination of 2+ variables).

Example code below. Say that using the `pigs` data, I want to compare all diets to the low percent fish diet. Note how in the `nd` data frame, "fish" only has 9% associated with it. However, when I run `emmeans`, the function does not pick up on the nesting, and while the control is correct, the treatment groups also include various values of fish and percents. Which means that the [p-value](/questions/tagged/p-value) adjustment is wrong.

So the two approaches I can think of:

1. How do I make `emmeans` pick up on the nesting in this case, or
2. How do I do the `dunnettx` adjustment manually (=I can use adjustment "none", then pull out the tests I actually want, and adjust the p-value myself?).

```
    library(emmeans)
    library(dplyr)

    pigs.lm <- lm(log(conc) ~ source + factor(percent), data = pigs)
    nd <- expand.grid(source = levels(pigs$source), percent = unique(pigs$percent)) %>%
        filter(percent == 9 | source != "fish")

    emmeans(pigs.lm, trt.vs.ctrl ~ source + percent, 
        data = nd, covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE)
```

Appreciate your help.

The suggestion to use `include` worked perfectly. Posting my code here in case anyone else has the same issue in the future.

```
library(emmeans)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pigs.lm <- lm(log(conc) ~ source + factor(percent), data = pigs)
nd <- expand.grid(source = levels(pigs$source), percent =     unique(pigs$percent)) %>%
    filter(percent == 9 | source != "fish")

ems <- emmeans(pigs.lm, trt.vs.ctrl ~ source + percent, 
    data = nd, covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE)

# to identify which levels to exclude - in this case, 
# I only want the low-percent fish to remain as the ref level
aux <- as.data.frame(ems[[1]]) %>%
    mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
    filter(!grepl("fish", source) | ID == 1)

emmeans(pigs.lm, trt.vs.ctrl ~ source + percent, 
    data = nd, covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE, include = aux$ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't think filtering the data is the solution.

If your goal is to compare the marginal means for `source` with the (fish, 9 percent) combination, you can do it by constructing two sets of emmeans, then subsetting and combining:

```
emm1 = emmeans(pigs.lm, "source")
emm2 = emmeans(pigs.lm, ~source*percent)
emm3 = emm2[1] + emm1      # or rbind(emm2[1], emm1)
```

Then you get

```
> confint(emm3, adjust ="none")
 source percent emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 fish   9         3.22 0.0536 23     3.11     3.33
 fish   .         3.39 0.0367 23     3.32     3.47
 soy    .         3.67 0.0374 23     3.59     3.74
 skim   .         3.80 0.0394 23     3.72     3.88

Results are averaged over some or all of the levels of: percent 
Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> contrast(emm3, "trt.vs.ctrl1")
 contrast        estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
 fish,. - fish,9    0.174 0.0366 23 4.761   0.0002 
 soy,. - fish,9     0.447 0.0678 23 6.595   <.0001 
 skim,. - fish,9    0.576 0.0696 23 8.286   <.0001 

Results are averaged over some or all of the levels of: percent 
Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 3 tests
```

Another (much more tedious, more error-prone) way to do the same thing is to get the EMMs for the factor combinations, and then use custom contrasts:

```
> contrast(emm2, list(con1 = c(-3,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0)/4,
+                     con2 = c(-4,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0)/4,
+                     con3 = c(-4,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1)/4),
+          adjust = "mvt")

 contrast estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
 con1        0.174 0.0366 23  4.761  0.0002 
 con2        0.447 0.0678 23  6.595  <.0001 
 con3        0.576 0.0696 23  8.286  <.0001 

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: mvt method for 3 tests
```

(The mvt adjustment is the exact correction for which dunnettx is only an approximation. It doesn't default to mvt because it is computationally heavy for a large number of tests.)

In answer to the last part of the question, you may use `exclude` (or `include`) to focus on a subset of the levels; see `? pairwise.emmc`.